# Is there a website which will help me crowdsource the decision between similar images?

Tags: software-recommendation

Sometimes I took 2-3 slightly different photos, and I simply can not make my mind up as which to keep. Yes, this means that none of them is great.

Is there a dedicated public website where I could upload all similar photos and ask people which one is more appealing?

EDIT

I am aware that public opinion is not necessary the best one. But if you get the opinion from ppl you respect, you might actually learn something about your photos. So this is not about the "facebook crowd", but "curated circle" of opinions. Also, it does **not** means that you will go with the flow - you just want a feedback. You still can choose whatever looks the best to your artistic eye.

I could imagine a service dedicated to this...

EDIT 2

I have create a proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94985/photoreview

Comment: I vote for non off-topic as this question is relevant to photography.

Comment: The basic problem is that requests for websites or other similar resources never end up well on Stack Exchange. It's not a bad question, just one that isn't suited for the medium.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it on dpreview.com perhaps the samples forum, but I would suggest to you that you don't actually have to keep just one.

It might be best to consider who you want the photo for.  Is it for yourself, because in that case what other people think is irrelevant.  If it's for a specific person, then why not let them decide.  But if you're trying to choose the most popular, this does not always equate to the best.  I've often seen images voted higher simply because they've higher saturation level and despite a number of glaring flaws ( terrible focus, portraits with blown facial highlights, full length portraits with feet cropped out and, my sin of sins, blown wedding dresses.

So I'd be cautious about going the public route to selection.

Comment: The downsides you've described are not of public sharing and critique in general but of the quality of the DPReview community. Some "names" like Keith Cooper or Thom Hogan are most often seen there because of the site's size, but that size also means the overall/average quality of the community is not great.

Comment: Any public forum is going to suffer from those problems.  500pix, Flickr, F&S, all of them.  And in sites where you get to choose who can review you you're really just biasing the opinion base, so that's going tend to result in confirmatory bias in the end.  There's no winning by relying on these sites to make a decision that a photographer or client should be making on a personal basis, IMO.

Comment: You're assuming that you're limited to strangers by the nature of the internet. That's not true. In a smaller community like on FM you get to know people, see their own work, learn their tastes, and can know from that whose opinions to pay more or less attention to. Just like a photography club or artists group critique in real life.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely! There is a wonderful community at [Fred Miranda](http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/). There are 'Presentation' subforums for categories such as Architecture, B&W, Landscape, etc, which are an option for you. Generally that is for finished images, though. You probably want the [Photo Critique](http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/board/4) subforum.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a dedicated public website where I could upload all similar photos and ask people which one is more appealing?

There are quite a few, with [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com) being perhaps the best-known site that's dedicated to photos. Just upload the images in question and see which one garners more "fave" stars. [500px](https://500px.com) has the same feature, except they use hearts instead of stars. Facebook would also do nicely and has the bonus that you can have more control over the group of reviewers.

> So this is not about the "facebook crowd", but "curated circle" of opinions.

Most social networks, Facebook included, let you define groups of friends or associates and share items only with that group. You don't have to broadcast everything to the whole world. In fact, limiting access to the things you share is the feature that's probably most responsible for Facebook's success. The "curated circle" is exactly the point of social networks, and any service designed to provide that is going to look a lot like Flickr, Facebook, or Google+. Heck, Google+ even calls it's groups "circles."

That said, it sounds like you're looking for a circle of experts that's curated by someone else and available for your use. In that situation, you're really talking about something that's more like a service than a social group, and it's hard to imagine why the experts would participate. What's in it for them? Don't they have better things to do than to review strangers' photos? Sites like [Photos](http://photos.stackexchange.com) incentivize that kind of interaction with various forms of gamification (reputation, badges, hats, etc.), but mainly because the "experts" often get to learn from each other.

There are some Stackexchange sites dedicated to reviewing others' work, like [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). You could propose a similar site for photo reviews, but it might be tough to get enough backers to make it successful.

I think your best bet is to start with photo sharing/social network sites, but also to work on developing your ability to critique your own work. Reading is one way to do that. Another is taking a photography class where you work on assignments that focus on specific aspects of photography.

Comment: When I said 'curated', I dont necessary mean experts. Its just people which opinion you valuate. I would not mind to be in such circle, if someone calls me:)) I hate the quick way of adding hearts/likes/pluses. So CodeReview is probably the closest to what i would like to see.

Comment: @igor The key is that the "experts" are whoever you say they are. I agree, I'm not likely to find myself rubbing elbows with famous photographers, but there are plenty of people whose opinions I value and who also talk to me on a regular basis. Those would by my "experts."

Comment: @celeb nice, this is exactly what i think about. Here is the proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94985/photoreview

Comment: @igor I'm still not entirely clear on what kind of feedback you're looking for. Do you just want people to decide between two similar photos? Or are you looking for a critique of one or more photos?

Comment: @celeb By people providing the critique, it will help you choosing. So choosing per-se is less important here; the feedback is more. For example, you can ask for feeling, thoughts about composition, level of saturation, level of post-production. It may be on one photo, or more photos, or to choose one from many. It's all a 'review' :)

Comment: @igor Which photo gets stars on flickr has little to do with which one is better ... But flickr has several critique groups where you can ask for human feedback. https://www.flickr.com/search/groups/?q=critique

Comment: @Szabolcs thanx. Lets make one here  :)

Comment: @igor Realistically, it is very unlikely that this proposal will go through (at least in its current form). [It is not a good fit for the StackExchange format...](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) That shouldn't stop you from trying, but you might at least want to think through the example questions and not make then A-or-B choices.  What would be the purpose of voting on such a site?  Which answer gets accepted? Why is this better as a Q/A site than as a discussion forum?  It sounds like you are looking for something that has an interface for A/B choices instead.